request.getParameter returns null in jsp/ servlet
request.getParameter returns null in servlet dopost method. I have checked http request its sending correct value. I have verified this in chrome network tab, but in servlet the value for request.getParameter("UserQuery"); is coming null , not the whats the issue tried few solutions from google but nothing seems to be work
JSP code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Chatbot</title>
    <style>
        /* Add responsive CSS styling for the chat interface */
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        #chat-container {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 50%;
            margin: auto;
            height: 400px;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }
        #chat-input {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 5px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        #chat-submit {
            padding: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .chat-message {
            margin: 5px 0;
        }
        .user-message {
            text-align: right;
        }
        .bot-message {
            text-align: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Chatbot</h2>
    <div id="chat-container">
        <!-- Chat history will be displayed here -->
        <div id="chat-history"></div>
    </div>
    <form   id="chat-form"  method="post"  >
        <input type="text" id="chat-input" name="userQuery" required placeholder="Type your message here..." />
        <input type="button" id="chat-submit" value="Send" onclick="return submitChatForm(event);" />
    </form>

    <script>
        // JavaScript to handle form submission and display chat history
        function submitChatForm(event) {
             event.preventDefault();
            var userQuery = document.getElementById("chat-input").value;
             
            // Create a chat message element for the user's message
            var chatHistory = document.getElementById("chat-history");
            var userMessageElement = document.createElement("div");
            userMessageElement.className = "chat-message user-message";
            userMessageElement.innerText = "You: " + userQuery;
            chatHistory.appendChild(userMessageElement);

            // Send the form data using AJAX
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("UserQuery", userQuery);

            fetch("chatbotServlet", {
                method: "POST",
                body: formData
            })
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => {
                // Create a chat message element for the bot's response
                var botMessageElement = document.createElement("div");
                botMessageElement.className = "chat-message bot-message";
                botMessageElement.innerText = "Bot: " + data;
                chatHistory.appendChild(botMessageElement);

                // Clear the chat input field
                document.getElementById("chat-input").value = "";

                // Scroll to the bottom of the chat history
                chatHistory.scrollTop = chatHistory.scrollHeight;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error("Error:", error);
            });

            return false; // Prevent form from submitting the traditional way
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Servlet code:
package com.java.chatbot;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;



import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
 

// Servlet implementation class ChatbotServlet
 
 
public class ChatbotServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ChatbotServlet() {
        super();
    
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           log("get method called");
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         
           response.setContentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
     
            String userQuery1 = request.getParameter("UserQuery");
           
            log("userQuery" + userQuery1);
            String botResponse = getBotResponse(userQuery1);

            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.print(botResponse);
            out.flush();
    }
    private String getBotResponse(String userQuery) {
        String botResponse = "";

        // Database connection setup
        try {
            // Replace with your database connection details
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chatbot_responses", "root", "");

            // Query to get random response based on user's query
            String query = "SELECT answer FROM chatbot_responses WHERE question = ? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            stmt.setString(1, userQuery);
           
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                botResponse = rs.getString("answer");
            }
            log("BOTRES" + botResponse);

            // Close resources
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } 
        
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            botResponse = "Sorry, there was an error processing your request.";
        }
        

        return botResponse;
    }

}

web.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd" version="5.0">
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>ChatbotServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ChatbotServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.java.chatbot.ChatbotServlet</servlet-class>
   
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ChatbotServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/chatbotServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <display-name>chatbot</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  
</web-app>

i have googled it before trying stackoverflow but nothing worked for me

Exactly what request, including URI, arguments and parameters, was requested?

Since you use FormData object with the fetch API the content is encoded as multipart/form-data and and parameters didn't parse correctly. You will always get null if you try to get the request parameters.
You need to change the content type header to application/x-www-form-urlencoded and convert the form data object. You can do it using URLSearchParams.
fetch("chatbotServlet", {
                method: "POST",
                body: new URLSearchParams(formData)
            })


